# Closable linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis

We have normal spaces $(E, \vert \vert * \vert \vert  )$ and $(F, \vert \vert * \vert \vert  )$ and operators $S \in L(E, F)$ (linear and continuous) and $T:  E \supseteq D(T) \rightarrow F$, where $D(T)$ is the domain of $T$. I have to show that $S +T$ is closable iff $T$ is closable. Also that $\overline{S+T} = S + \overline{T}$. Unfortunately i do not have any idea how I should start.

Comment: For this problem it will help you to write down exactly the definition of what it means for an operator to be closeable. Write it down once for "$T$" and once for "$S+T$" and use continuity of $S$ to connect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We denote by $\Gamma_A$ the graph of operator $A$.

Assume that $T$ is closable. It is enough to prove that $\overline{\Gamma_{S + T}} = \Gamma_{\overline{T} + S}$. Let $(x_n,y_n) \in \Gamma_{S + T}$ - be a converging sequence to some $(x,y) \in \overline{\Gamma_{S + T}}$. Then $y_n = (S+T)x_n = Sx_n + Tx_n$. Since $S$ is bounded sequence $Sx_n$ converges to $Sx$. And therefore sequence $(x_n, y_n - Sx_n)$ is a sequence in $\Gamma_T$ that converges to $(x,y-Sx)$. It follows that $x \in D(\overline{T})$ and $y = (S + \overline{T})x$. Hence $\overline{\Gamma_{S + T}} \subset \Gamma_{\overline{T} + S}$. Now consider an element $(x,y) \in \Gamma_{\overline{T} + S}$. Then $(x,y - Sx) \in \Gamma_{\overline{T}}$ and therefore there exists a sequence $(x_n,y_n) \in \Gamma_T$ that converges to $(x,y - Sx)$. Then sequence $(x_n,y_n + Sx_n)$ converges to $(x,y)$ and belongs to $\Gamma_{S+T}$. Hence $(x,y) \in  \overline{\Gamma_{S + T}}$. Therefore $\overline{\Gamma_{S + T}} = \Gamma_{\overline{T} + S}$.

Conversely assume that $S+T$ is closable. Then $T = (S + T) - S$ is closable by previous result.